# Goa'uld population growth

Tags: stargate

In *Summit* at 15:00 Jacob/Selmak says: *Now for the first time they (Goa'uld, red) are showing zero population growth, we're not sure why*. In *Last Stand* at 32:00, Daniel says: *I have figured out why the Goa'uld population hasn't been growing much lately*.

I've watched both episodes again but either I missed the explanation or it's not actually mentioned. What is the reason for their population growth stagnation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Goa'uld have been devouring their larva, as seen in the image below:

[image: Osiris eats a larval Goa'uld]

Here's a larger image of another system lord snacking:

[image: Tastes Great! Less Filling!]

This happens *just* before Daniel makes his report on finding the reason for the stagnant growth.

This, in and of itself, wouldn't account for the complete lack of population growth, but SG-1 and the rest of the Tau'ri have been killing a LOT of Jaffa...and each one that dies takes the larval symbiote with it.

Comment: Not to mention knocking off System Lords left right and centre, at least some of whom must have been Goa'uld queens...

Comment: @Richard: Hathor (who hadn't been in the breeding pool for thousands of years) was the only confirmed queen they eliminated.  Most of the rest of the System Lords represented themselves as male (whatever that might mean for their species).  It's unlikely they had the time and/or inclination to spend attached to a huge egg sack floating in water, instead of in a plush chamber with servants and...snacks.  That said, most of them probably had a queen or two somewhere - where else would the larva come from?

Comment: I did always find that scene to be a weak explanation of why Goa'uld population growth had stopped. The ritual cannibalism involved was portrayed as a ceremonial, possibly even religious rite, not the sort of thing that would happen very often or be indulged in by minor Goa'uld. That is the closest the episode comes to an explanation, however, so one could posit that the Goa'uld are using ritual cannibalism as a form of poulation control, in addition to what is shown onscreen.

Comment: We don't see them killing other system Lords but at one point they start listing who they've deposed and there are multiple names that we've not seen them interact with. .

Comment: I did consider this. However, each Jaffa matures around a dozen Goa'uld symbiotes, and there are many more Jaffa than Goa'uld. I always assumed the majority of Goa'uld were discarded anyway so eating them won't make a huge dent.

Comment: @Richard: I recall the scene you mention.  SG-1 was personally involved in each listed System Lord's death and they were all on the show.  Been a while since you watched it?